# Flutter/Dart Extract just the Date and Time?

Tags: mysql, regex, flutter, dart

How would I either reformat, convert or extract just the date and time from this string in Dart/Flutter? The String comes from the default timestamp in my MySQL database;

```
2021-08-11T11:38:09.000Z
```

So what I need is something like this;

```
  2021-08-11 11:38
```

I was thinking perhaps something like;

```
final String? shortime = timestamp?.replaceAll(RegExp(''), '') ?? '';
```

But I'm not sure what to use as the regex.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.parse("2021-08-11T11:38:09.000Z");
```

then create a function to check the input number:

```
String checkNum(int x){
   return x<10?"0${x}":x.toString();
}
```

now you can use this function as follow:

```
  print(checkNum(x.year));
  print(checkNum(x.month)); // and so on...
```

let me know if you had any related problems.
here is an example:
[image].

Comment: Did you try the solution? It does not take into account that the date and time should be padded with 0 to the number is always two digits.

Comment: I will update my answer, thank you.

Comment: I actually used your first answer. The edited one gave this error; A value of type 'Object' can't be returned from the function 'checkNum' because it has a return type of 'String?'.

Comment: @Meggy I edited my answer again (just missed () in front of toString!). Now you can have access to each parameter you want like (x.hour, x.minute, and so on), also checkNum function checks that return String always have two digits for example it returns "01" instead of "1"

Comment: @Meggy did it work?

Comment: I used your first answer.  Android Studio gave this error on the function; A value of type 'Object' can't be returned from the function 'checkNum' because it has a return type of 'String?

Comment: @meggy did you tried replacing x.toString with x.toString()?  In checkNum function?

Comment: I think the problem is that x is not an integer.

Comment: @Meggy I checked it again, it works in the dartpad. https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true

Comment: I'm not sure why but it didn't work in Android studio. At any rate your first answer worked.

Comment: fine... so I think you can neglect `numCheck` function and do not use it... Could you use it as an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 3):

Since the provided timestamp is supported by `DateTime.parse` you could do something like this:

```
void main() {
  final dateTime = DateTime.parse('2021-08-11T11:38:09.000Z');
  print(convertDateTimeToString(dateTime)); // 2021-08-11 11:38
}

String convertDateTimeToString(DateTime dt) => '${dt.year}-'
    '${dt.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-'
    '${dt.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} '
    '${dt.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:'
    '${dt.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
```

Alternative, you can use a package like [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) which supports formatting `DateTime` using a formatting pattern:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final dateTime = DateTime.parse('2021-08-11T11:38:09.000Z');
  final format = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
  print(format.format(dateTime)); // 2021-08-11 11:38
}
```